# How to include white space when searching for a string in text file

Tags: python, counter, traversal

Each user is marked in one of the following two ways: `[donorStatus] => donor` or `[donorStatus] => notADonor`.

The string `notADonor` is unique so I am able to use the following function to count instances of it successfully. However, `donor` appears within other, longer strings in the file, so I'd like to search for a more specific string like `=> donor`.

Searching for this yields 0 each time so I'm thinking it's the white space throwing it off and I can't figure out how to work around that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
from collections import Counter;

count = Counter();

for line in open ('data.txt', 'r'):
  for word in line.split():
    count[word] += 1

print count['=> donor']
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `split()` splits every whitespace, including the one between `>` and `donor`. To split at every whitespace EXCEPT the ones with `>` before it, use `re.split('(?<!>)\s+', line)`:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

count = Counter()

for line in open ('data.txt', 'r'):
  for word in re.split('(?<!>)\s+', line):
    count[word] += 1

print count['=> donor']
```

**Regular expression explained:**

`(?<!a)b`  is the expression for at [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) matching every `b` not preceded by `a`. Therefore, `(?<!>)\s+` matches every every whitespace characters (`\s+`) not preceded by `>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense to me but for some reason, it returns 5. I know there should be roughly 800-900 matches so I'm not sure why the number is so low.

Comment: @user2901181 Sorry, my mistake. I had written the `regex` to include the whitespace AND the previous letter, making all words `=> dono` because `r` was cut off. I've corrected the answer and tested it.

Comment: Excellent, it's working just as I need it to now. I have only a little experience with regex so I appreciate the explanation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`, `count` and `sum`;

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Select only the lines that interest us

```
possible = [ln.strip().split() for ln in lines if '[donorStatus]' in ln]
```

Now find the donors;

```
print sum(ln.count('donor') for ln in possible)
```

Comment: They state though that the word donor appears independently in other sections of the file, so that won't work.

Comment: It states "occurs in longer strings". I interpreted that as "XXXdonorYYY", not "XXX donor YYY".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. `donor` actually does occur both in longer strings AND in other places independently. So this function will return a count that is slightly too high. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @user2901181 Is the `[donorStatus]` on a separate line?

Comment: @RolandSmith `[donorStatus] => donor/notADonor` is all on one line. Other instances of the word donor occur elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re
from collections import Counter;

count = Counter();

for line in open ('data.txt', 'r'):
  for word in line.split():
    if re.search('=> donor', line, re.I):
        count[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the results you're after

```
def count(word):
    counter = 0
    for line in open ('c:\\data.txt', 'r'):
        if word in line:
            counter += 1
    return counter

print count('=> donor')
```

Comment: Perhaps the term 'word' should be changed to 'string' or 'phrase' as you specifically asked about including white space in the search term

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing this for this particular list and want to keep things fast, I'd first check if "=>" is used anywhere else in the file.

If it isn't, save yourself the time and just use `donor_count = count['=>'] - count['notADonor']` for a constant-time solution.

Otherwise, you may want to change your for loop to:

```
for line in open ('data.txt', 'r'):
    if '=> donor' in line:
        count['=> donor'] += 1
    // split and continue counting as needed, etc.
```

or use a regex, if you're going to use regular expressions for other things in the parsing. Otherwise, it's not likely to be worth the import just for this check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The file I'm scanning through is actually a text representation of a PHP array so there are quite a few `=>` in there (about 500,000 to be exact...it's a big file). The modification you suggested seems to be returning an accurate number though.